# Taking the 'and' of a list by folding in Scheme

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

In the book *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* 
by H. Abelson and G. J. Sussman with J. Sussman, 
the `accumulation` or `fold-right` is introduced in Section 2.2.3 as follows:

```scm
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

I tried to use this to take the `and` of a list of Boolean variables, by writing:

```scm
(accumulate and 
            true 
            (list true true false))
```

However, this gave me the error `and: bad syntax` in DrRacket (with `#lang sicp`), 
and I had to do this instead:

```scm
(accumulate (lambda (x y) (and x y))
            true
            (list true true false))
```

Why? I believe it has something to do with how `and` is a special form, 
but I don't understand Scheme enough to say. 
Perhaps I'm just missing some obvious mistake...

Comment: You are right. `and` is a special form that does not obey the regular rules of evaluation. Specifically, not all its arguments will be evaluated. It only evaluates its arguments until it finds one that is `#f`, in which case the entire `(and ...)` is `#f`. Because it is not a procedure, you can't pass it as an argument to `accumulate`.

Comment: This is covered in depth in Chapter 4 of SICP.  Sect 4.1 covers both how precedures are implemented and how special forms are handled.  Sect 4.2 discusses an alternative way to implement behaviour like 'and' as a procedure that can be used with an accumulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question: `and` is a special form (not a normal procedure!) with special evaluation rules, and `accumulate` expects a normal procedure, so you need to wrap it inside a procedure.

To see why `and` is a special form, consider these examples that demonstrate that `and` requires special evaluation rules (unlike procedures), because it short-circuits whenever it finds a false value:

```
; division by zero never gets executed
(and #f (/ 1 0))
=> #f

; division by zero gets executed during procedure invocation
((lambda (x y) (and x y)) #f (/ 1 0))
=>  /: division by zero
```