# How to run and on a list of booleans in scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm working on map-ing over a list to preform logic on it to make decisions and I keep coming aback to producing something like this:

```
((#t #t #f)(#t #t #t)(#t #t #t)(#f #t #t)(#t #f #t))
```

What I need is to change the above list of list into

```
(#f #t #t #f #f)
```

I had the thought using `and` which would do the logic I want; `(and #f #t #t) ⇒ #f`. But I'm not sure how to move the lists of booleans around so that I can run `and` on them. I thought about using `apply` but it didn't work:

```
(apply and '(#t #t #f))
While compiling expression:
Syntax error:
unknown location: source expression failed to match any pattern in form and
```

Is there a way to run `and` on the booleans in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`and` is a special form and not a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60094131/201359), we need to do something like this (using [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) and [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29)):

```
(define lst '((#t #t #f) (#t #t #t) (#t #t #t) (#f #t #t) (#t #f #t)))

(map (lambda (sl)
       (foldl (lambda (e acc) (and e acc)) #t sl))
     lst)

=> '(#f #t #t #f #f)
```

In some Scheme dialects (Racket, for instance) we can write an even simpler expression by taking advantage of [`curry`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29), [`identity`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._identity%29%29) and [`andmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29):

```
(map (curry andmap identity) lst)
=> '(#f #t #t #f #f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define input '((#t #t #f)(#t #t #t)(#t #t #t)(#f #t #t)(#t #f #t)))

(map (lambda (a) (every (lambda(x) x) a))
     input)
```